# The possible range of the mean of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

In my book about stochastic processes, the author says:

Let X be a nonnegative independent random variable and F an arbitrary distribution for X. Then, by the assumptions that $X \geq 0$ and $F(0)<1$, it follows that $0 < \mu \leq \infty$, where $\mu = E[X] =  \int_0^\infty x dF(x)$.

But I can't understand in order to get $0 < \mu \leq \infty$, why we need the assumption $F(0) < 1$. I think the author wanted us to know if $F(0)=0$, the result would be different.

Could you please explain the necessity of $F(0)<1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F(0)=1$ is the statement that $P(X\leq0)=1$.

Combination of this with condition $X\geq0$ leads to $P(X=0)=1$ and consequently $\mu=0$.

This contradicts $0<\mu\leq\infty$.